# kgsearch.entities.search - what format should "ids" parameter take?

Tags: google-apis-explorer

The docs for the `[Knowledge Graph API][1]` are very sparse; they mention I can use "ids" to search for a specific list of entities instead of using a query. I have some entity IDs that were reported by the natural-language API as "mentioned entities" in documents, such as:

kg:/g/11c58ncq2b

When I provide one of these as an "ids" query-string parameter, I get a terse 400:

"code": 400,
  "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
  "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"

Same result if I try to use the bare string "11c58ncq2b" or other variants.

Does anyone know what format is expected here?

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to have two parts: one simple, one complex.

The simple: although it's not documented anywhere, stripping the `kg:` URL scheme from the entity IDs returned by the natural language API turns them into IDs that the kgsearch API can grok. Thus, searching for ID `/g/11c58ncq2b` will respond with 200 whereas `kg:/g/11c58ncq2b` will respond with 400,

The complex: it seems that these entity IDs are not consistent between versions of the APIs. Thus, entity IDs returned by `v1beta` of the natural language API frequently fail to yield any result when I search `v1` of the KG API. After learning the format of the `ids` parameter, my searches still kept returning mostly-empty results. Once I switched to consistently using `v1` of all APIs, my searches began to yield useful results.